# Правильне вживати/писати слово "здавалося" чи "здавалось?

Tags: вживання-слів, правопис, милозвучність

Просто розмовляючи, поставила під сумнів свою вимову. Коли ж почала розбиратися як правильно вимовляти чи писати це слово то за результатами запросу в інтернеті зрозуміла що це питання бентежить мене одну)
І хоч різниця тільки в одній літері, навіть вимова та інтонація слова змінюється...

Академічний тлумачний словник з Української мови мені не дав відповіді... http://sum.in.ua/s/zdavatysja

А у творах Т.Г.Шевченка використовується і та і інша версія слова:
"Ну що б, здавалося, слова...
Слова та голос — більш нічого"

"Веселеє колись село Чомусь тепер мені, старому, Здавалось темним і німим..."

Невже можна вважати правильними обидва слова, хоч і з різними кінцівками?

Comment: Якщо ж Вас влаштовують мої відповіді і Ви їх приймаєте, ставте, будь ласка, прапорець "✔". Таким чином збільшується рейтинг. Дякую за розуміння!

Answer (score 3):

На скільки я знаю, обидва постфікси є нормативними. На їх вживання впливає лише милозвучність. Якщо наступне слово розпочинається на приголосний, або взагалі збіг приголосних, слід вживати `-ся`. Якщо ж на голосний, тоді `-сь`. Подібну інформацію знайшла на цьому сайті: [Постфікс -ся і -сь](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%8F/)

Comment: Сторінка за посиланням не містить заявленої інформації. Будь ласка, поправте посилання, щоб воно вказувало не на home page сайту, а безпосередньо на потрібну статтю

Comment: Вже  виправила посилання.

Comment: А я додав уточнення «наступне слово», якщо я правильно зрозумів ідею вашої відповіді.

Comment: так, саме так! Дякую!